# Como instalar um apk direto da minha aplicação, com titanium studio?

Tags: android, mobile

Preciso conseguir atualizar um aplicativo, sem a necessidade dele estar na Play Store ou do cliente acessar a internet para fazer o download do mesmo. Preciso de algo automático, mas sem interação com o cliente. É possível? Como pode ser feito?

Comment: coloca o `.apk` na memoria do dispositivo e execute-o

Comment: @Math está correto. Só configurar as opções de desenvolvimento do aparelho pra permitir isso.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser apenas instalar você pode usar o adb... Inves de transfirir para a memoria do celular.

```
adb install -r /caminho/do/arquivo.apk
```

obs.: o arquivo apk precisa ter a mesma assinatura caso voce esteja atualizando.